# How to set a Wpf Window as the Owner of a Winforms Form

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

How to set a System.Windows.Window as the Owner of a System.Windows.Forms.Form?

After I searched for this for a while only to realize that I already have the answer in one of my utils classes I decided to put the answer on stackoverflow. Hopefully someone finds this useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isn't `SetParent` considered "more correct" than `SetWindowLong` with `GWL_HWDPARENT` (-8)?

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
```

Comment: This worked great for me setting the WPF window as parent of Win32 dialog.

Answer (score 12):

Use this method:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]

private static extern int SetWindowLong(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

/// <summary>
/// sets the owner of a System.Windows.Forms.Form to a System.Windows.Window
/// </summary>
/// <param name="form"></param>
/// <param name="owner"></param>
public static void SetOwner(System.Windows.Forms.Form form, System.Windows.Window owner)
{
    WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(owner);
    SetWindowLong(new HandleRef(form, form.Handle), -8, helper.Handle.ToInt32());
}
```

Comment: Note  To write code that is compatible with both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows, use SetWindowLongPtr. When compiling for 32-bit Windows, SetWindowLongPtr is defined as a call to the SetWindowLong function.