# How do you show a Winforms dialog from a WPF window?

Tags: wpf, winforms

The inverse of this question has been answered a number of times.

```
public static void SetOwner(object activeWindow, object dialog)
{
    if (IsWindow(dialog) && IsWindow(activeWindow))
    {
        (dialog as Window).Owner = (activeWindow as Window);
    }
    else if (IsForm(dialog) && IsForm(activeWindow))
    {
        (dialog as Form).Owner = (activeWindow as Form);
    }
    else if (IsWindow(dialog) && IsForm(activeWindow))
    {
        var wih = new WindowInteropHelper(dialog as Window);
        wih.Owner = (activeWindow as Form).Handle;
    }
    else if (IsForm(dialog) && IsWindow(activeWindow))
    {
        var dialogForm = dialog as Form;
        var ownerWindow = activeWindow as Window;
        // What goes here?
    }           
}
```

Comment: This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095763/how-to-set-a-wpf-window-as-the-owner-of-a-winforms-form

Comment: You don't have to specify an owner, Form.ShowDialog() will find one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Winform dialog with WPF window as Parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822164/winform-dialog-with-wpf-window-as-parent)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a class that implements the WinForms `IWin32Window` interface  and returns the WPF window's handle (using [`new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper.handle.aspx)), then pass that to the form's `ShowDialog`.

Comment: I had to refactor my IDialogService API a little bit, but the new solution works great now. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

To expand upon SLaks' answer, here is an example such class:

```
public class WpfWindowWrapper : System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window
{
    public WpfWindowWrapper(System.Windows.Window wpfWindow)
    {
        Handle = new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(wpfWindow).Handle;
    }

    public IntPtr Handle { get; private set; }
}
```

It could be used like this from a WPF window's code-behind:

```
var winForm = new MyWinForm();
winForm.ShowDialog(new WpfWindowWrapper(this));
```

In this way the Winform dialog acts as a proper child of the WPF window, with the correct modal behavior.