# Winform dialog with WPF window as Parent

Tags: wpf, winforms

I have a WinForm dialog and I want to set its Parent property to a WPF window.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider passing parameter to `ShowDialog` method instead of using `Parent` property.

You can write helper class

```
class Wpf32Window : IWin32Window
{
  public IntPtr Handle { get; private set; }

  public Wpf32Window(Window wpfWindow)
  {
    Handle = new WindowInteropHelper(wpfWindow).Handle;
  }
}

public static class WindowExtensions
{
  public static IWin32Window GetWin32Window (this Window parent)
  {
    return new Wpf32Window(parent);
  }
}
```

After that you can just write

```
winFormsWindow.Show(yourWpfWindow.GetWin32Window());
```

Comment: The `Handle` property of the created objects is null. Do you know why?

Comment: Is your wpf window already created? Try using this code when the window is already loaded. I didn't have this problem in my case. Probably this article will be helpful http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/wpf/thread/5f89ac58-d2ef-4ac0-aefb-b2826dbef48a

Comment: This does not appear to work properly - the `new Wpf32Window` never gets released, and even after the program ends, the original process remains because that new window was never properly deallocated.

Comment: What is needed is: 
`Form winFormsWindow = new Form();
IWin32Window win32WinVer = yourWpfWindow.GetWin32Window();
winFormsWindow.Show(win32WinVer);
((Window)win32WinVer).Close();`
 instead of the above call.

Comment: I get System.InvalidCastException when calling ((Window)win32WinVer).Close()

Comment: You cannot cast result of `GetWin32Window` to `System.Windows.Window`. You don't need to close handle obtained from `WindowInteropHelper` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312883/windowinterophelper-handle-do-i-need-to-release-it). You can close your WPF window using `yourWpfWindow.Close()`. But I don't see the point of doing so, when you want it to be Parent of your new dialog (probably you want to close child when your application exits). Or, if you can use a modal dialog (`ShowDialog()` instead of `Show`), this will ensure that Main WPF window closes after the 'child' Winform dialog