# WindowInteropHelper.Handle — do I need to release it?

Tags: wpf, winapi, com

In WPF I'm getting IntPtr handle using this code:

```
IntPtr mainWindowHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow).Handle
```

When I finish using this handle, do I need to release it in anyway (e.g. using Marshal.FreeHGlobal() method) ?

EDIT: I was thinking about Marshal.FreeHGlobal(), not Marshal.Release(), sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not in any way related to COM, Marshal.Release() does not apply.  You simply get a copy of the native window handle, it does not have to be released.  You need to stop using the handle when the window is destroyed.  Signaled by the Window.Close event.

Comment: Great, thanks, I guess I was thinking too hard about it and confused myself. I actually meant Marshal.FreeHGlobal() method, not Marshal.Release(). Is it still same situation? And if it is, when would you use Marshal.FreeHGlobal() ?

Comment: No, it doesn't have anything to do with memory either.  Again: don't do anything to "release" it.