# Do I need to free IntPtr handle aquired by Win32 API or WindowInteropHelper

Tags: c#

right now I am acquiring the window and System Menu's handle by doing

```
IntPtr hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
IntPtr menuHandle = GetSystemMenu(hwnd, false);
```

`WindowInteropHelper` is built in and `GetSystemMenu` is Win 32 API

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);
```

My question is, do I need to release either of the handles? If I do, how and when should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

It is a reference to a managed window, so the memory gets released when the window is closed. 
You don't need to free the pointer.

Look also at this answer:  [WindowInteropHelper.Handle — do I need to release it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312883/windowinterophelper-handle-do-i-need-to-release-it)

Similarly, also the following instruction is getting a copy/pointer of the menu already created and managed within the window lifecycle.

Comment: how about the GetSystemMenu one