# Open WinForm from WPF application?

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms

I've created an WPF and WinForm Application, what i need to do is
open the WinForm from the WPF application. Both are in the same solution but they're diferent projects.

I tried the following:

```
Dim newWinForm as New MainWindow
newWinForm.show()
```

I found a possible solution from here: 
[Opening winform from wpf application programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152403/how-do-you-show-a-winforms-dialog-from-a-wpf-window)

But i dont understand what exactly i have to do. I hope you could help me. Thanks!

Comment: a `Process.Start("Winform.exe");` could be an alternate method...

Comment: Yes, i did that also, but the WPF app is a login form, so i dont think it is a good choice. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally you need to host your form in a [WindowInteropHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms618134.aspx), 
like following in the WPF window Button.Click event handler:

C#:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  Form1 form = new Form1();
  WindowInteropHelper wih = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
  wih.Owner = form.Handle;
  form.ShowDialog();
}
```

VB:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim form As New Form1()
    Dim wih As New WindowInteropHelper(Me)
    wih.Owner = Form.Handle
    form.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

And of course you need to add reference/import of your project and System.Windows.Forms.dll

Comment: Hello, now when the WinForm app is starting it trows an exception at this line:
Dim conexion As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CONN").ConnectionString)

object reference not set to an instance of an object

It's a Instance Variable.

Greetings!

Comment: It just means something in your code is null or nothing. It might because that you missed some of init code to build your connection string or etc. My sample code doesn't created a new process, so your WinForm app never starts. If you wanna start a new process, you  try the @Jeremy Thompson's comment `Process.Start("Winform.exe");`

Comment: I just got it working, but now i have this issue:

When the new WinForm has been rendered, the controls look like a Win98 application, an old look and feel. Greetings!

Im on W7

Comment: You need to enable the visual style by calling the `System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();`
            `System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);` before your window is created.  You could take a look at the Program.cs in your WinForm project. Cheers!

Comment: No, you don't need to use any Interop or fancy stuff. You simply need to reference the WinForm project from the WPF one, create the WinForm object, and call `Show()` on it.

Comment: @gog Please notice the forms are in different projects and one of the project is WinForm and the other WPF. Your comment does not apply in this case.

Comment: @Nandostyle I understood that. And I say it again: (1) Add a reference to the WinForm project from the WPF one; (2) create the WinForm object; (3) call `Show()` on it. That's all is needed. We just migrated a whole **VS Solution** containing multiple **VS Projects** from WinForms to WPF, just changing the main project to WPF first, and then migrating the other projects to WPF last, one by one. We absolutely never needed any WindowInteropHelper of any kind. Perhaps something has changed in 2020 or so, but that's what we did. We used .NET 4.5 / 4.6 / 4.7.

Comment: Tried this and got error 'Forms cannot own themselves or their owners'. Shouldn't the code be setting form.Owner to something?

Answer (score 1):

Let's pretend that you the two projects are called `WPFApp` and `WinFormApp`.

Both of them declare a `MainWindow` class, which is the main application window.

In order to open the `WinFormApp` `MainWindow` from the `WPFApp` application, you simply need to perform the following on the `WPFApp` project:

1. Add a reference to the `WinFormApp` project
2. Add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms`
3. Create a new `WinFormApp.MainWindow` object
4. Call `Show()` on it

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Terry didn't work for me. I wanted to return to my WPF Window, but then I had to add the window's Handle as an argument to the ShowDialog() method. Which I could get fixed.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49802029/1770778) from user dapi on a similar question worked better in my case:

```
var winForm = new MyFrm();
winForm.ShowDialog(new WpfWindowWrapper(Window.GetWindow(this)));
```

With a small helper class:

```
public class WpfWindowWrapper : System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window
{
    public WpfWindowWrapper(Window wpfWindow)
    {
        Handle = new WindowInteropHelper(wpfWindow).Handle;
    }

    public IntPtr Handle { get; }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

it is impossible loading a win form from WPF application.
so you can do like this:

1- Create a User control in winform project and add all form's element to user control

```
public partial class myUserControl : UserControl, IDisposable 
{
...// All Form Code and element put here
}
```

2- create a wpf window and put a Grid into that:

```
<Grid Name="grid">

</Grid>
```

3- on Wpf window Code behind like this :

```
public partial class myWpfWindow: Window
{
    public myWpfWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myUserControl = new myUserControl ();
        System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost winformHost = new 
             System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();
        winformHost.Child = myUserControl;

        grid.Children.Add(winformHost);  // --> <Grid Name="grid">

    }

}
```

4- add two reference to project:`WindowsFormsIntegration,  System.Windows.Forms`

Comment: This example matches the example shown:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-windows-forms-control-in-wpf