# The calling thread must be STA,because many UI components require this

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

Why am I getting the Error

> The calling thread must be STA,because many UI components require this

I am already using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke :

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {

                var windialog = new MyView(Ids);
                var result = windialog.ShowDialog();
            });
```

Comment: Is `DocumentUploaderView` (after your edit: `MyView`) a windows-forms component? If so, you might want to see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16577222/23354

Comment: MyView is a WPF Window

Comment: Have a look at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stathreadattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Looks like the current app dispatcher isn't the UI dispatcher.  You're doing this very early on in the application lifecycle, aren't you?  Whatever you're doing--stop it.  Back up.  1) What is your goal?  2) How are you trying to accomplish this?  You're stuck, obviously.  The solution is to do something else, which depends on 1 and to a lesser degree 2