# How can I set Form Window's owner to WPF Window?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

My application is built in WPF .NET Framework.

I have an WPF MainWindow and I want to make several FormWindows as children of the WPF MainWindow. When making child WPF Window of parent WPF Window, I can simply put `Owner = this` to child window but it does not work on Form Window, of course.

is there any way to make it possible?

thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open WinForm from WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577122/open-winform-from-wpf-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot set the `Owner` property of a WPF window to anything else than another WPF window.

There is a [WindowInteropHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) class that has an `Owner` property that can be set to the HWND of a form:

```
Form1 form = new Form1();
WindowInteropHelper wih = new WindowInteropHelper(wpfWindow);
wih.Owner = form.Handle;
```

Another suggestion would be to skip the forms and move the *contents* of the forms into WPF windows, for example using the [WindowsFormsHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) control.

Comment: Is it? Says who? The answer has been accepted - over a year ago...